# Retrieve users created between two dates from ldap

Tags: java, date, filter, fetch, ldap-query

Can someone help me how to use the filter conditions to fetch user lists created between two dates(from and to dates) from LDAP in java . In ldap date is shown in **DD-MON-YYYY** however on searching with (*dateattr=09-JAN-2019*) for example returns 0 results

Answer (score 3):

[Date (GeneralizedTime) LDAP SearchFilters](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Query%20Basic%20Examples#section-LDAP+Query+Basic+Examples-DateGeneralizedTimeLDAPSearchFilters) shows how to Match any dates Greater than or equal to 20190101000000Z but less than or equal to 20200101500000Z

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=exampleuser,example.com" -w secret -p 389 -h server.example.com -b "dc=example,dc=com" -s sub "(&(createTimestamp>=20190101000000Z)(createTimestamp<=20200101500000Z))"
```